# Pyspark - How to get random values from a DataFrame column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have one column in a DataFrame which I need to select 3 random values in Pyspark. Could anyone help-me, please?

```
+---+
| id|
+---+
|123| 
|245| 
| 12|
|234|
+---+
```

Desire:

Array with 3 random values get from that column:

```
**output**: [123, 12, 234]
```

Comment: You can do `df.select("id").limit(3).show()` ?

Comment: It should be randomly

Comment: `df.select("id").rdd.takeSample(false, 3).collect()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can order in random order using `rand()` function first:

```
 df.select('id').orderBy(rand()).limit(3).collect()
```

For more information on `rand()` function, check out [pyspark.sql.functions.rand](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.rand).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that's probably more performant.

You can fetch three random rows with this code:

```py
df.rdd.takeSample(False, 3)
```

Here's how to create an array with three integers if you don't want an array of Row objects:

```py
list(map(lambda row: row[0], df.rdd.takeSample(False, 3)))
```

`df.select('id').orderBy(F.rand()).limit(3)` will generate this this physical plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
TakeOrderedAndProject(limit=3, orderBy=[_nondeterministic#38 ASC NULLS FIRST], output=[id#32L])
+- *(1) Project [id#32L, rand(-4436287143488772163) AS _nondeterministic#38]
```

This [post](https://mungingdata.com/pyspark/random-values-arrays-columns/) discusses fetching random values from a DataFrame column in more detail.